# CMake project builds but shows include error in LSP

Tags: c++, cmake, language-server-protocol

I'm working on a C++ project using `ccls` (the LSP language server) and `lsp-mode` in Emacs. I also have a CMake project definition for my project. My project builds correctly with `make` using the `Makefile` generated by CMake, but `ccls` says that my `#include` is not found.

Here's the project structure:

```
+ CMakeLists.txt
+ main.cpp
+ src/
|\
| + SomeClass.cpp
| + SomeClass.hpp
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(includefail)

set(simple_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(simple_VERSION_MINOR 1)

add_executable(
  includefail
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/SomeClass.cpp
  )

target_include_directories(
  includefail PRIVATE
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
  )
```

This generates the following `compile_commands.json` (which is what `ccls` uses):

```
[
{
  "directory": "/home/user/code/c/include-fail/build",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/home/user/code/c/include-fail/src  -o CMakeFiles/includefail.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/user/code/c/include-fail/main.cpp",
  "file": "/home/user/code/c/include-fail/main.cpp"
},
{
  "directory": "/home/user/code/c/include-fail/build",
  "command": "/usr/bin/c++  -I/home/user/code/c/include-fail/src  -o CMakeFiles/includefail.dir/src/SomeClass.cpp.o -c /home/user/code/c/include-fail/src/SomeClass.cpp",
  "file": "/home/user/code/c/include-fail/src/SomeClass.cpp"
}
]
```

`src/SomeClass.hpp` looks like this:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass();
private:
    int x;
};
```

`src/SomeClass.hpp` looks like this:

```
#include "SomeClass.hpp"

SomeClass::SomeClass() {
    x = 1;
}
```

And `main.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include "SomeClass.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* arv[]) {
    SomeClass sc = SomeClass();
    return 0;
}
```

It's in `main.cpp` where I get the error from LSP. It says `'SomeClass.hpp' file not found`.

So why is `ccls` not able to find this include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ccls` tries to find `SomeClass.hpp` in the root of your project.
It should be fine when you change the first line of your `main.cpp` to this (At least for me it resolved the error):

```
#include "src/SomeClass.hpp"
```

Comment: I perhaps should have made this clear in my question: I want to _not_ have to use the `src/` path in the `#include` because it's handled by the `CMakeLists.txt` file. I'm seeing it as redundant in the `#include`. `ccls` is able to find vendor libraries that live outside my project and I'm hoping that it should be able to do the same with my internal "library".

Comment: I've just tried configuring `lsp-mode` to use `clangd` instead of `ccls` and now this `#include` is not flagged as an error.

Comment: Happy to hear that you could resolve your problem! I thought that I have tried your example code both with `ccls` and `clangd` and saw no difference but maybe I am wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was to use `clangd` instead of `ccls`.

In Emacs with `lsp-mode` I didn't find it super obvious how to set this up. `lsp-mode` doesn't seem to have a way of specifying which language server (or "client") you want to use for a language when there's more than one available. Instead, it has a kind of denylist of language servers you *don't* want to use. So my C++ Emacs set up now looks like this:

```lisp
(defun my/c++-mode ()
  (setq lsp-disabled-clients '(ccls))
  (setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers '(c/c++-cppcheck c/c++-gcc))
  (lsp))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my/c++-mode)
```